# Finding groups which have two values in another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query, group-by

Given the following sample rows:

```
MTYPE RNO VAL
S     1   V1
S     1   V2
S     1   V3
R     1   V4
S     2   V5
S     2   V6
R     3   V7
R     3   V8
```

How can I list groups of RNO which has both 'R' and 'S' in any of its rows in MTYPE column. In the above sample data the result should be:

```
MTYPE RNO VAL
S     1   V1
S     1   V2
S     1   V3
R     1   V4
```

As RNO=1 group has both S and R rows in MTYPE column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, find the RNO that with both `R` and `S`. Then join back to your table to select the rows

```
with
rno as
(
    select  RNO
    from    yourtable 
    group by RNO
    having  min(MTYPE) = 'R'
    and     max(MTYPE) = 'S'
)
select  *
from    rno  r
        inner join yourtable t  on  r.RNO   = t.RNO
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an aggregate, I would suggest using [INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql), as in:

```
;WITH src AS
(
    SELECT t.RNO
    FROM #t t
    WHERE t.MTYPE = 'S'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT t.RNO
    FROM #t t
    WHERE t.MTYPE = 'R'
)
SELECT t.*
FROM #t t
    INNER JOIN src ON t.RNO = src.RNO;
```

If you use `MIN()` and `MAX()` to determine the intersection of rows containing the values you want, you'll see incorrect results If there are rows in the source table containing values that are occur before `R` or after `S` in the particular collation used by the column\table\database, then the query will return incorrect results.

As an example, consider this [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;

CREATE TABLE #t
(
    MTYPE   char(1) NOT NULL
    , RNO   tinyint NOT NULL
    , VAL   char(2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #t (MTYPE, RNO, VAL)
VALUES 
      ('Q', 1, 'V1')
    , ('S', 1, 'V2')
    , ('S', 1, 'V3')
    , ('R', 1, 'V4')
    , ('S', 2, 'V5')
    , ('S', 2, 'V6')
    , ('R', 3, 'V7')
    , ('T', 3, 'V8');


;with
rno as
(
    select  RNO
    from    #t
    group by RNO
    having  min(MTYPE) = 'R'
    and     max(MTYPE) = 'S'
)
select  *
from    rno  r
        inner join #t t  on  r.RNO   = t.RNO;
```

The output returns zero rows:

| MTYPE | RNO | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |

Whereas the `INTERSECT` operator returns any RNO that has *both* S and R `MTYPE` values:

| MTYPE | RNO | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q | 1 | V1 |
| S | 1 | V2 |
| S | 1 | V3 |
| R | 1 | V4 |

If your source table has a substantial number of rows, you may want to split the `INTERSECT` and the `SELECT` into two operations:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #x;

SELECT t.RNO
INTO #x
FROM #t t
WHERE t.MTYPE = 'S'
INTERSECT
SELECT t.RNO
FROM #t t
WHERE t.MTYPE = 'R'

SELECT *
FROM #x
    INNER JOIN #t ON #x.RNO = #t.RNO;
```

I'd also consider adding the following index to the table:

```
CREATE INDEX t_MTYPE
ON #t (MTYPE, RNO)
INCLUDE (VAL);
```

Comment: Thanks Hannah, I find this one good because I can extend it for say three values in the MTYPE column. I wish I can mark multiple answers as solution to my problem.